# React - Trigger an Action on Stateless Component Mount

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

My question is conceptual (just started picking up React).

Here's what I have:
Main Component (MC) mounts a Stateless Component (SC1). After a few dropdown selections and a "Continue" button click it mounts a SC2.

How do I run some queries right after the button click to display on SC2? *(componentDidMount() doesn't seem to be available on a stateless component)*

There has to be the "right way" to code this but I'm not sure what that is.

Btw. I am using React with Meteor and React Router. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to take advantage of component lifecycle methods like componentDidMount, which it sounds like you do for 'SC2', you have no choice but to write them as ES6 classes and not use functional stateless components.